# Compatible html tag to show flash on html?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, html, object-tag

There are various ways to show flash(swf file) on html, for example, `object` or `embed` tags.

I want to support IE6-9, FireFox3-, Chrome, Safari, and as many other browsers as possible.
(especially IE6-9)

But I also want to use simple tag as possible.

What is the best way to write html tag to show flash(swf file)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend SWFObject - it creates simple and easy to maintain code:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

There's even a generator to automatically create the embed code:

http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/generator/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much for introducing the nice library. Is there information about which browsers does SWFObject support?

Comment: It should support nearly all the browsers (except maybe very old versions). SWFObject is used by YouTube and even Adobe so it should be safe to use.

Comment: SWFObject works on every common desktop browser and even on the Wii or PS3. It's also a very good solution to display alternate content for browsers without Flash or JavaScript support (eg. iOS devices).

Answer (score 2):

SWFObject supports all browsers. in fact, if you build flex using Flash Builder 4 then it automatically uses swfObject to embed your swf into the html